# How to do Interpolation Search on strings?

Tags: c, string, interpolation

I'm trying to make an Interpolation Search, but I realized that strings cannot be like integer, which is needed in the interpolation search function.
I've stumbled some solution like making a = 1, b = 2 , and so on, and then added all of those into another integer array

```
char c = 3;
char o = 15;
char w = 23;
```

and so-on,
but that doesn't really works when i try to print, per se

```
print("%d", data[0]); which is cow, it shows another number, 6356204
```

I tried that before the data is sorted. I also found some solution online, but it is in java, and i can't seem quite understand, since i only know c language.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int compare(const void *a, const void *b){

    const char *ia = (const char *)a;
    const char *ib = (const char *)b;

    return strcmp(ia, ib);
}

int SearchInterpolation(char * data[], int n, char searchKey){

    int position, low, high;
    low = 0;
    high = n-1;
    do{
        position = (searchKey - data[low]) * (high-low) / (data[high] - data[low]) + low;
        if(strcmp(data[position], searchKey) == 0) return position;
        if(strcmp(data[position], searchKey) > 0) high = position - 1;
        else low = position + 1;
    } while ((strcmp(searchKey, data[low])>0) && strcmp(searchKey, data[high]) < 0);
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char argv){

    char * data[10][50]={"cow", "sheep", "dog", "goat", "chicken", "duck", "bird", "fish", "bee", "horse"};
    char c = 3;
    char o = 15;
    char w = 23;
    print("test : %d\n", data[0]);
    int size1 = sizeof(data[0]);
    int n = sizeof(data) / size1;
    printf("%d\n\n", n);
    int i, j;
    char key[10];

    for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%s\n", data[i]);
    }

    qsort(data, n, size1, compare);
    printf("=============\n\n");

    for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%s\n", data[i]);
    }
    printf("\nSearch: "); scanf("%s", &key);
    fflush(stdin);

    int index = SearchInterpolation(data, n, key);

    if(index != -1){
        printf("%s found at index - %d", key, index);
    } else{
        printf("Data is not found");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out how to change strings into integer,
Can anyone kindly help me to do the interpolation search with strings ?

Comment: the posted code does not compile!   When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: here is the first problem in the code: *untitled1.c:20:31: error: invalid operands to binary - (have ‘int’ and ‘char *’)*  for line: `position = (searchKey - data[low]) * (high-low) / (data[high] - data[low]) + low;`  There are also some 30-40 warnings about other problems in the posted code

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking about an algorithm for code that does not compile

Answer (score 1):

String length is potentially huge, as if of enormous precision.

Two strings can be quite "close".  Converting to a number and then subtracting would take lots of precision.

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrst_x"
"abcdefghijklmnopqrst_y"
```

> How to do Interpolation Search on strings?

To interpolate, we need both a `numeric f_abs(string)` (for overall value) and `numeric f_dif(string1, string2)` (for useful differences, even if nearly equal).

Note that in the end, use `strcmp(string1, string2)` for an equality test.

I recommend using `double`.

```
double f_abs(const char *s) {
  const unsigned char *us = (const unsigned char *) s;
  double val = 0.0;
  double f = 1.0;
  while (*us) {
    f /= UCHAR_MAX + 1;
    val += *us++ * f;
  }
  return val;
}

double f_dif(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
  const unsigned char *us1 = (const unsigned char *) s1;
  const unsigned char *us2 = (const unsigned char *) s2;
  double val = 0.0;
  double f = 1.0;
  while (*us1 && *us2) {
    f /= UCHAR_MAX + 1;
    val += (*us1++ - *us2++) * f; // difference taken before scaling
  }
  while (*us1) {
    f /= UCHAR_MAX + 1;
    val += *us1++ * f;
  }
  while (*us2) {
    f /= UCHAR_MAX + 1;
    val -=  *us2++ * f;
  }
  return val;
}
```

Even `double f_dif(s1, s2)` will be useless once strings have a common prefix of maybe 110 characters.  Passed that, I recommend code goes from interpolation to bisection.

---

As a dictionary of words is *clumpy* (groups of words "near" each other), consider alternating an interpolation with bisection to not get stuck in areas where interpolation is not useful.  [BTDT](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/BTDT)